# See if you have a specific dependency in command line

Tags: dependencies, deb

How can you see if you have a dependency on Ubuntu? I want to see if I have the `libc6` dependency for `prboom`. Is there anyway to do this? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Specifically for libc6, you have it installed. If you didn't, your Ubuntu wouldn't be working. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dpkg -l` command lists packages matching a given pattern. If the package is installed, the first column of the output should be `ii`, for example:

```
$ dpkg -l libc6
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name             Version       Architecture  Description
+++-================-=============-=============-======================================
ii  libc6:amd64      2.19-0ubuntu6 amd64         Embedded GNU C Library: Shared librari
ii  libc6:i386       2.19-0ubuntu6 i386          Embedded GNU C Library: Shared librari
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see whether a package is installed, which version is installed and which versions are available and from where using the command

```
apt policy PACKAGENAME
```

or for older systems (don't know exactly since when `apt` is included and supports the `policy` command)

```
apt-cache policy PACKAGENAME
```

This will result in an output like that:

```
$ apt policy libc6
libc6:
  Installed: 2.23-0ubuntu5
  Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 2.23-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

If there's anything written after `Installed:` other than `(none)`, you have that package installed and the string there represents the installed version.

By the way, `libc6` is an essential core part of Ubuntu, your system could not work without it at all anyway.